# C++ pod initialization via default c'tor

Tags: c++, standards

Consider this POD:

```
struct T
{
   int i;
   char c;
};
```

In which C++ standard was the requirement of POD members be initialized to zero via default c'tor introduced (or was it in the standards from the beginning)?

Yes, that means without user specified c'tor, 'i' and 'c' will both be initialized to 0.
See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/80ks028k%28VS.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know if I have understood your question properly or not.

> that means without user specified c'tor, 'i' and 'c' will both be initialized to 0.

Not necessarily.

For example:

```
T x; // `i` and `c` are uninitialized

T *ptr = new T; // `i` and `c` are uninitialized
T *pptr = new T(); //`i` and `c` are zero initialized as `T()` implies value initialization

T x(); // x is a function returning a type T and taking no arguments.
```

To be precise `value initialization`(C++03 Section $8.5/5) is something you are looking for. It was introduced in C++03.

Answer (score 3):

What you're talking about is properly called "value initialization". It was introduced in C++03 (it's defined at §8.5/5, in case you want to look at the details).